# On click jQuery удаляет елементы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Проблема вот в чем, данный код должен скрывать один блок и показывать другой. Но от просто очищает весь блок .main-content. В заметку скажу что блок .filterwrap создается динамически.

```
<section class="main-content">
<section class="resultwrap"></section>
<section class="filterwrap"></section>
</section>



 $('html').on('click', '.backtoparam', function(e) {

        console.log('returnToFilter');
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.resultwrap').hide();
        $('.filterwrap').fadeIn(300);

return false;


});
```

Comment: Какое-нибудь содержимое в `<section class="filterwrap"></section>` есть?

Comment: Что значит очищает? Что в сорс-коде видно?

Comment: Судя по предоставленному коду, так как `$('.filterwrap')` не содержит каких-либо данных, вы их и не видите на экране. Реальное положение вещей лучше проверьте через веб-инспектор, который предоставляет ваш браузер.

Comment: Содержимое есть, но до клика в соурскоде есть html после клика .main-content пустой. Я не начинающий программист, просто такое в меня впервой. Может есть какие-то варианты такого поведения ?

Comment: @MaksDevda, ну, данный код ничего не удаляет, даже если бы и хотел. `Hide` и `fadeIn` управляют только видимостью элементов. Я бы  попробовал удалить javascript и посмотреть, будет ли разница. Если нет, то, соответственно, с уверенностью искать в другом месте (возможно, где-то есть еще обработчик).

Comment: Спасибо!
Уже сам так сделал, в другом файле была копия обработчика, но с другим кодом. Проект достался в доработку. Всем спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="main-content">
<section class="resultwrap">
     One
</section>
<section class="filterwrap">
     Two
</section>
</div>
<a class="backtoparam" href="#">Link</a>
```

Можно упростить скрытие/показ пары блоков вот так:

```
<script>
   $(document).on('click','.backtoparam',function(){
       $('.resultwrap,.filterwrap').toggle();
       return false;
   });
</script>
```